# How to prevent stackoverflow exception when two controls update each other

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two controls which update each other. There are two textboxes that take only numbers. They update each other in that they add 1 to each other. So if textbox1 is changed to 45 then it will update textbox2 to 46 and vice versa. I am using `mvvm` pattern so the update logic is in the setter propery. Here is the code:

```
private string _selectedTicker2;

public string SelectedTicker2
{
    get { return _selectedTicker2; }
    set 
    { 
        if(_selectedTicker2 != value)
        {
            _selectedTicker2 = value;
            SelectedTicker3 = (int.Parse(_selectedTicker2) + 1).ToString();
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTicker2");
        }

    }
}

private string _selectedTicker3;

public string SelectedTicker3
{
    get { return _selectedTicker3; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedTicker3 != value)
        {
            _selectedTicker3 = value;
            SelectedTicker2 = (int.Parse(_selectedTicker3) + 1).ToString();
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTicker3");
        }

    }
}
```

If textbox1 is changed by the user then it should not be updated by textbox2 and vice versa. Is there a simple way to solve this?

Comment: The overflow is happening because you are using the public properties inside of your setter. See John's answer, which shows he is using the private properties instead.  That is your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possibly a naive approach, but wouldn't changing them like this work to stop the `StackOverflowException`?:

```
set 
{ 
    if(_selectedTicker2 != value)
    {
        _selectedTicker2 = value;
        _selectedTicker3 = (int.Parse(_selectedTicker2) + 1).ToString();
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTicker2");
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTicker3");
    }

}
```

and

```
{
    if (_selectedTicker3 != value)
    {
        _selectedTicker3 = value;
        _selectedTicker2 = (int.Parse(_selectedTicker3) + 1).ToString();
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTicker3");
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTicker2");
    }

}
```

If this isn't suitable, you'll probably need a tertiary variable to hold some kind of state to prevent you from causing a loop.

Comment: ended up going this route. More simple for me

Answer (score 1):

One way around it is to have a private variable that keeps track of whether or not the value is being updated by the code or by the user. By default, it will be set so any changes made are by the user. Then our code would change it briefly while updating the other textbox, after which we change it back again"

```
private bool _changeIsFromUser = true;
private string _selectedTicker2;

public string SelectedTicker2
{
    get { return _selectedTicker2; }
    set 
    { 
        if(_selectedTicker2 == value) return;

        _selectedTicker2 = value;

        // If this change is being made by the user, update the other control
        if (_changeIsFromUser)
        {
            // "Notify" the other control that our code is making this change
            _changeIsFromUser = false;
            SelectedTicker3 = (int.Parse(_selectedTicker2) + 1).ToString();
            _changeIsFromUser = true;
        }

        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTicker2");
    }
}

private string _selectedTicker3;

public string SelectedTicker3
{
    get { return _selectedTicker3; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedTicker3 == value) return;

        _selectedTicker3 = value;

        // If this change is being made by the user, update the other control
        if (_changeIsFromUser)
        {
            // "Notify" the other control that our code is making this change
            _changeIsFromUser = false;
            SelectedTicker2 = (int.Parse(_selectedTicker3) + 1).ToString();
            _changeIsFromUser = true;
        }

        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTicker3");
    }
}
```

Comment: If an exception occurs in `int.Parse`, this will leave `_changeIsFromUser` in the false state. So better wrap it into a try .. finally like this: `try {SelectedTicker3 = (int.Parse(_selectedTicker2) + 1).ToString(); } finally { _changeIsFromUser = true; }`

Comment: Yes, or just use `TryParse` instead.